# How to fix this error in Rstudio (Random Number Generation)

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when I run this command, please help

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
Error in RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding") : 
  unused argument (sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

Comment: [`?Random`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html) doesn't include the argument `sample.kind`, did you mean `normal.kind`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `sample.kind` argument was introduced in `R 3.6.0.` Make sure that you are using at least that version or any above.

From `Details` in `?Random` on `3.6.2`

> sample.kind can be "Rounding" or "Rejection", or partial matches to
>   these. The former was the default in versions prior to 3.6.0: it made
>   sample noticeably non-uniform on large populations, and should only be
>   used for reproduction of old results. See PR#17494 for a discussion.

Comment: when I click on check for updates in Rstudio it's saying that I have the latest version of R

Comment: I pretty sure Rstudio checks for the version of Rstudio not of R. What's your output for `version$version.string`?

Comment: > version$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)"

Comment: This shows that you have `R` version `3.5.3`. The argument you are specifying was introduced in version `3.6.0`, [update your `R` version](http://www.r-project.org) in order to fix this. But please also note the documentation: "should only be used for reproduction of old results"!